# jQuery UI DatePicker date convert to RFC 3339 format

Tags: date, datepicker, rfc3339

Currently working on the Google Calendar API and basically my end will provide Start and End date for user to pick the date and time. But would like anyone to advise how to convert them from (DatePicker/TimePicker/input field) to RFC 3339 format (e.g. 2013-07-24T10:00:00.000-07:00).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();
var timeZone = date.getTimezoneOffset();
alert(date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + "T" + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes()  + ":" + date.getSeconds() + "." + date.getMilliseconds() + (timeZone > 0 ? "-" : "+") + Math.floor(Math.abs(timeZone) / 60) + ":" + Math.abs(timeZone) % 60);
```