# on submit change date format from dd M yy to "2015-01-28T00:00:00+00:00" datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, date, datepicker

I am currently using a datepicker in wordPress allowing the user to select a date. On submit, how can I change the current format of 'dd M yy' to something like 2015-01-28T00:00:00+00:00 so it can be submitted into a database later on. As well as check for validation, but I think this will be a different question.

Currently I have the following to declare the date picker :

```
//  triggers the calendar to open.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#deadline_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd M yy',
        minDate: 0
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP code

```
$datetime= date("c", strtotime(" 2015-01-28"));
echo $datetime;  //Output :  2015-01-28T00:00:00+00:00
```

**jQuery Code**

```
var dateVar = "2015-01-28";
var date=new Date(dateVar);
var timeZone = date.getTimezoneOffset();
alert(date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + "T" + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes()  + ":" + date.getSeconds() + "." + date.getMilliseconds() + (timeZone > 0 ? "-" : "+") + Math.floor(Math.abs(timeZone) / 60) + ":" + Math.abs(timeZone) % 60);
```

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296712/datetime-from-how-make-a-rfc-3339)**

Comment: Sorry, but I am using JS not php.

Comment: I think wordpress made in `PHP`

Comment: yes it is, but my validation and on submit code is in a JS file :/

Comment: That won't take the exact time.. It will fill the rest with 0s.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I would do this in JS? @noc2spamツ

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807806/jquery-ui-datepicker-date-convert-to-rfc-3339-format

Comment: That does half help, but I would liek to use the year, month and day that the user has inputed using the datepicker, if that is possible.